# Why does Kjartan not notice anything?

Tags: katla

In the show *Katla*, Grima writes a letter to her partner, Kjartan, saying that the person whom he will meet when he gets home is not her, and that she will explain things later. He seemingly dismisses this, as well as her firm insistence that he has been talking to someone who is not her, and that her sister is a duplicate, as her having psychological issues. Still, it must have put the idea in his head, not to mention that he must at least have heard of the drama with Gunhild, since the town is miniscule, and that he surely knew that the body discovered bore a strong resemblance to Ása (even though he did not have the DNA results).

Still, since this is all second-hand information that defies logic and science as he knows it, his reluctance to accept it is somewhat understandable. Perhaps less so is the scene in the final episode, where Grima and meteorite-duplicate Grima (m-Grima) are sitting in the kitchen chatting. Kjartan comes in, overhears their conversation and asks if Grima is talking to herself. Then he comes into the kitchen, walks up to Grima, and kisses her, somehow missing m-Grima sitting at the kitchen table five feet away, walks over to his room without noticing anyone about a foot away from him, even though he should *have* to see m-Grima in his peripheral vision. M-Grima then comes over to his room, and they chat. He then leaves and walks through the kitchen, somehow failing to notice Grima in the background. Finally, he asks m-Grima if she changed her hairstyle, apparently not noticing that she changed from a plain tan shirt to a heavily-patterned wool sweater within about 60 seconds.

It is unclear whether he noticed

> The massive bloodstain on the curtains or the body of one of the Grimas buried barely covered in the shallow sand outside their house, after she committed suicide.

When compared with how quickly other characters caught on, Kjartan seems extraordinarily incapable of noticing anything. Is he simply incredibly unperceptive, or in active denial?

Comment: Unfortunately, I fear this is a bad case of "We have our characters fail to point out obvious things that would clear everything up to keep up the drama." Compare how Grima wants to show the DNA results from the frozen corpse to Kjartan (she's still behaving like a normal person here), but when he fails to notice the other Grima in the kitchen for several minutes, at no point does she just stand next to her double and say "Hey Kjartan, look, there's two of us." This completely shattered my suspension of disbelief.